Comparing folder tree files across systems?
TL;DR:

Plan was to migrate my library of Photos + Data from Windows to Mac setup
About 4TB of files across 2 drives, on each Windows + Mac
Windows drives are NTFS, Mac drives are APFS and HFS+
I copied/moved files multiple ways, some were interrupted+resumed, etc.
Both systems currently network share their respective drives to the other system. They are directly connected over ethernet
Currently all files APPEAR to have finally copied across; FreeFileSync on Windows and Carbon Copy Cloner on Mac are both "happy" and don't want to sync/update any more files (based on file size+mod time)
BECAUSE of the interruptions and the massive amount of files+data, can I do a file contents/hash compare?
FreeFileSync offers a file contents comparison method, but it results in needing to transfer every file across the network and hash it, effectively taking (more than?) the time tojust re-transfer everything all over again

I am just finishing up moving my Windows setup over to Mac, and now have my ~4TB of files moved over. I ended up using a few different methods to move the content over, and a few of the methods failed during the process... so that was fun.
As of now I've used a combination of exposing the drives to the network share on both ends, and using FreeFileSync + Carbon Copy Cloner (on Win + Mac respectively) to compare them. And now I am at the point where their file sizes and timestamps are matching, nothing reported left to sync.
HOWEVER
Due to the huge volume of files transferred, the different methods, and some interrupted transfers... I'd really sleep a LOT better at night truly knowing the files are actually the same, copied over entirely... and not just some placeholder/representation of the file size?
FreeFileSync on Windows looks like it has an option to compare FILE CONTENTS, but it's SUPER slow. I think it's basically grabbing each file off the mac across the network and hashing it... which is effectively doing the whole copy over again. Sidenote: It seems there's basically no difference from comparing "File contents" vs a hash of the contents? And given these are my files, that I've just copied across, I'd have to imagine even an md5 hash, with POSSIBLE collisions, is more than adequate?
Is there any way I can optimize this a bit more? Sort of like a Host<>Server setup where the Windows program can just ask the Mac for the hash of the file or something, rather than generating it remotely?
To be clear: I do not wish to SYNC anything anymore, as I have an expectation that is complete... and if not, I'd probably want ti look into it manually. But some output or visual comparison saying "these files are the same", "these files are NOT the same"

Primitive, but simple: 1. On each machine,make a slash-separated value list of all files. E.G., forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @path/@fsize">files.csv in Windows. 2. Import into a spreadsheet and sort by name. 3. compare file sizes, allowing for a nominal delta between sizes because of differing file systems. (Why / and not comma? I believe it's not used in filenames in Mac or Windows.)
